# sort from a file with grouped data

Tags: python, database, file, sorting, runtime-error

i have a made a sort for my program however when I run it it sort it into all one line group , as I need to be sorted by surnames and for the data to shift with the sort and I am not sure how to fix help would be apricated
an example line of the csv file is
'connor'   'beginner' '20.4'

```
def sort():
    filename = "classmarks.csv"
    file_handle = open(filename, "r")
    words = []
    for column in file_handle:
        words += column.split()
    file_handle.close()
    print (sorted(words))
```

Comment: Can you add sample lines from csv file.

Comment: just added one for you there